# Clarification between a module and a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

I'm reading Kenneth Hoffman's Linear Algebra, Ed2.

In $\S5.5$ it talks about Module and Vector Spaces:

> (1) ￼If $K$ is a commutative ring with identity, a **module over $K$**
>   ( or a **$K$-module**) is an algebraic system which behaves like a
>   vector space, with $K$ playing the role of the scalar field.
>
> (2) A **basis** for the module $V$ is a linearly independent subset
>   which spans (or generates) the module. This is the same definition
>   which we gave for vector spaces; and, the important property of a
>   basis $\mathscr B$ is that each element of $V$ can be expressed
>   **uniquely** as a linear combination of (some finite number of) elements of $\mathscr B$.
>
> (3) The reader is well aware that a basis exists in any vector space
>   which is spanned by a finite number of vectors. But this is not the
>   case for modules.
>
> (4) Definition. The $K$-module $V$ is called a **free module** if it
>   has a basis. If $V$ has a finite basis containing $n$ elements, then
>   $V$ is called a **free $K$-module with $n$ generators**.
>
> (5) Definition. The module $V$ is **finitely generated** if it
>   contains a finite subset which spans $V$. The **rank** of a finitely
>   generated module is the smallest integer $k$ such that some $k$
>   elements span $V$.
>
> (6) We repeat that a module may be finitely generated without having a
>   finite basis.
>
> (7) Theorem 5. Let $K$ be a commutative ring with identity. If $V$ is
>   a free $K$-module with $n$ generators, then the rank of $V$ is $n$.
>
> (8) From Theorem 5 we know that ‘free module of rank $n$’ is the same
>   as ‘free module with $n$ generators.’

I'm quite lost here --

Q1: (3) and (6) seem are talking about the same thing, that a module $V$ could be spanned by a finite number of elements $\{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n\}$, but $V$ might not have a finite basis. Does this mean that in module $V$ there might be some element $\alpha$, that it can be expressed as a linear combination of $\{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n\}$, but in **two** different ways? (So this violates the "**uniquely**" requirement in the  **basis** definition?) If so, could you pls give me some examples of such a $V$?

Q2: however, (8) says: ‘free module of rank $n$’ is the same as ‘free module with $n$ generators.’ Seems this conflicts with (3) and (6)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1: Yes. As an example take $V=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = \{ [0],[1]\}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Then you have $$[1] \cdot 1 = 3 \cdot [1] = 5 \cdot [1] = \cdots$$
are all different representations of $[1]$ of the form $\lambda \cdot [1]$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Q2: No. (8) means that IF a module is free and is generated by $n$ elements, then every other basis has $n$ elements. (8) is not talking about modules which are not free. (3) and (6) just say that there exist some non-free modules.

Comment: thank you so much, now I get it!